# Angular Material Errror when using pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Looking at the docs for Angular Material and ran into an issue when utilizing the mat-autocomplete. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Error** pipe does not exist on type observable

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {pipe} from "rxjs/util/pipe";
import {startWith} from 'rxjs/operator/startWith';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-filter-example',
  templateUrl: './my-template.html'
})
export class AutocompleteFilterExample {

  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  options = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
  ];

  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(val => this.filter(val))
      );
  }

  filter(val: string): string[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: is your local version of rxjs 5.5.x?

Comment: No my current version is 5.4.2

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have imported RxJs pipe operator at the start

import 'rxjs/utils/pipe'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your local version of rxjs is ^5.5.0

Answer (score -1):

Are you using this import :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Comment: Hi Davi, yes I am importing the rxjs/Observable